# UIColor patternImage not working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, uitabbar, uicolor

I'm currently trying to make my Swift app compatible with iOS 7. For some reason, I cannot set the Tabbar background as I did it on iOS 8. This is my code:

```
tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "green.png")!)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.translucent = false;
```

from the documentation:

Discussion
  This color is made translucent by default unless you set the translucent property to NO.

Comment: Ok, looks like creating an Objective C function and calling it from Swift doesn't work.

Comment: Hint: just do that if the device is iOS 7, not on iOS 8. That caused an ugly black background on my iPhone 6.
Implement a check like this:

        let iosVersion = NSString(string: UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion).doubleValue;
        let iOS7 = iosVersion >= 7 && iosVersion < 8;
        
        if iOS7 { tabBar.translucent = false }